# Is there a way to find out what the local ip is of a website?

Tags: cmd, web, ip, external, local

Like i said in the title. Is there a way to find out what the local ip is of a website. If there is not, is it possible to make one?

So it must start with 192......

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I got your question at all. But when you want to know the ip from an website, simply resolve the domain (for example using dig, nslookup, etc).

When you want to know the internal network-ip of a webserver that is located behind a nat, I think there's no simple solution possible - unless you have access to the machine.